# What do I need to travel to the US?

Tags: usa, air-travel, international-travel, pandemics

I have a valid J1 visa with exception to the the travel ban. I have my flight ticket. It flies to one of those 13 airports.

What else do I have to do officially before I fly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Follow all safety procedures and be extra careful. Wear mask at all times, stay away from other people as much as possible, pick a seat in empty row (if possible), wash hands frequently, etc.
- Check Covid testing and quarantine requirements for the US state, county and city that
  you will be staying in.
- If you need to stay in quarantine for an extended time, arrange for it: Make sure you have a safe & well isolated place to stay, figure out how to get food & supplies, have a safe means of communications and ideally some local contacts.